# Applying border in grid structure in css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a grid struture with div of equal height and width but I am unable to apply the border
**CSS**

```
 .Container {
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.RowContainer {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}
.RowContainer .Cell {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid Black;


}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="Container">     
    <div class="RowContainer">
      <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p> </div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum
        </p>  </div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="RowContainer">
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum
        </p></div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></div>
        <div class="Cell"><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></div>
    </div>  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>    
</div>
```

I have two issues

1.
 border is not showing in the last row.

2.
As well as the border width seems unequal despite of applying same border property to all.

Comment: It's your overflow messing with your heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom border is not showing in ***either*** row because you have `height: 100%` on the `.Cell` and `overflow: hidden` on the `.Container`. What you are seeing under the first row is the top border for the second row.

If you set `height: 100%;` on the child of an element of `height: 200px` that has `overflow: hidden` and then you set a `border` of `1px` to that child, then that border *adds up on all sides*.

It makes that child element take up `202px` vertically. That's `1px` from top border **+** `200px` from height **+** `1px` from bottom border.

But the parent element has a height of **only** `200px` and `overflow: hidden`, which means that vertically, from the child element, what you see is the `1px` top border and `199px` of the child's height. There is still `1px` of its height and the `1px` bottom border which are hidden.

Second vertical border is thicker than the first, because you have there both the right `1px` border of the first cell and the left `1px` border of the second cell.

This would solve the issue http://dabblet.com/gist/3145644

Comment: yes you are right,it is because of overflow:hidden.Can you explain me why it is showing this behaviour

Comment: very nice explaination http://jsfiddle.net/nmqGD/ please check this fiddle I am trying to make border even

Comment: They are not two extra cells. The `.Container` is simply too large at `1000px`.You need to set its `width` at `806px` and no right-border on the `.Cell` http://jsfiddle.net/nmqGD/2/

Comment: yes true but why cell is not showing right border if I remove .Cell:last-child then also it is not showing right border.I actually want right border

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you try to explain it more clearly?

Comment: i mean I want the last cell of each row to have right border.all cells must be surrounded with border

Comment: It does have a border. If you don't like it, you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/nmqGD/7/ tweak the height, set a bottom and right border on each cell, a top border on the cells on the first row `.RowContainer:first-child .Cell {border-top:1px solid Black;}`, and a right border on the first cell of each row `.Cell:first-child {border-left:1px solid Black; }`. Or set borders all around and negative margins or tansparent some borders afterwards http://jsfiddle.net/nmqGD/8/

Comment: Because I want to see borders all around. A `height` of `99%` of `200px` is `198px` vertically. With borders of `1px` both top & bottom, as it is the case for the first row, that adds up to `200px` (`198px` height + `1px` border top + `1px` border bottom), exactly the `height` of the row container.

Comment: awesome this is great.Without you it was impossible.I never thought that css also can be so calculative

Comment: Can you suggest which method is method table or this one

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to create something that is table-like, why not just use tables?

```
<table class="container">     
    <tr>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
        <td><h1>lorum ipsum</h1><p>lorum ipsum epsum</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, tables are meant for tabular data and divs are for layout purposes.

Comment: thks for code but my boss doent want table ....I want to use div only.can u help me with this

Comment: Well, there are two other answers which can probably help you with your problem. You should really reconsider and use tables though - tables are built for displaying tabular data. You get much more control using them than you do using non-tabular markup.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow:hidden` on `.RowContainer` is hiding the border on the `.Cell` divs, because border is drawn outside the `.Cell`'s box, which is set to 100% height. Removing the `overflow:hidden` should reveal it again.

As for the unequal border, I can't say for sure since you didn't provide a jsfiddle to look at, but I'm guessing you mean the borders between the cells is thicker than it should be -- that's because each `.Cell` has a border all the way around, resulting in the left/right borders sitting next to each other, giving the appearance of a 2px border.

You can fix this by only setting border on the top and left sides of each `.Cell`, and then setting border on the bottom and right sides of the `.Container`.

Comment: yes removing overflow hidden is heling to see border but applying border on the top and left sides of each .Cell, and then setting border on the bottom and right sides of the .Container is not working

Answer (score 0):

remove your overflow:hidden

like  this

```
   .Container {
width:1000px;

margin:0 auto;


}



   .RowContainer {

height:200px;
clear:both;

}


 .RowContainer .Cell {
position:relative;
float:left;
height:100%;
width:200px;

  border:1px solid Black;
}
```

**The CSS Overflow**

Every single element on a page is a rectangular box. The sizing, positioning, and behavior of these boxes can all be controlled via CSS. By behavior, I mean how the box handles it when the content inside and around it changes. For example, if you don't set the height of a box, the height of that box will grow as large as it needs to be to accommodate the content. But what happens when you do set a specific height or width on a box, and the content inside cannot fit? That is where the CSS overflow property comes in, allowing you to specify how you would like that handled.

There are four values for the overflow property: visible (default), hidden, scroll, and auto. There are also sister properties overflow-y and overflow-x, which enjoy less widespread adoption.